# Exception: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3) Python

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

Trying to save a model in current directory of Python code.

```
bert_wordpiece_tokenizer.get_vocab()
bert_wordpiece_tokenizer.save_model("tokenizer")
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-48e7f902a270> in <module>
----> 1 bert_wordpiece_tokenizer.save_model("tokenizer")

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tokenizers\implementations\base_tokenizer.py in save_model(self, directory, prefix)
        325                 An optional prefix, used to prefix each file name
        326         """
    --> 327         return self._tokenizer.model.save(directory, prefix=prefix)
        328 
        329     def save(self, path: str, pretty: bool = False):
    
    Exception: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
```

Unable to understand the directory, the code is looking for.

Comment: is this FULL error message?

Comment: frankly I would expect this error if you would read file, or if you would write `path/filename` because it may run code in different folder then you expect and it could try to write in folder which doesn't exist (usually functions not create folder automatically). Did you try with ``/full/path/to/file.json` ? Maybe check `current working directory` - `os.getcwd()` - maybe it runs in wrong place and it has no privileges to do this.

Comment: @furas, Added the complete error msg. I have tried using different paths on my machine, but no success

Comment: error shows problem in internal code `...mode.save(directory, ...)` so it can suggest that it expects that `tokenizer` is a directory, and it may expect that this directory `tokenizer` already exists. So you may have to first create this folder. And if you want to save in file then maybe it needs extension - `tokenizer.json`